# How to get thumbnail image in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento-2.0

I have use this code in magento 2

```
$media_url = $storeObj->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
$baseimage          = $media_url.'catalog/product' . $_product->getImage();  

Output: http://localhost/smithbuy/pub/media/catalog/product/w/d/wd7500aaks.jpg

But, I want 
http://localhost/smithbuy/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/700x700/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe/w/d/wd7500aaks.jpg
```

Please help me.

Comment: $this->_imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')
                        ->setImageFile($image->getFile())
                        ->getUrl()     Use something similar to this

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to avail the thumbnail image in the Magento:

```
$Media = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
foreach ($Media as $image) {
    $image->getTypes();
}
```

getTypes() returns an array that may contain the following vlaues:

- image
- small_image
- thumbnail

If it contains thumbnail then it's the thumbnail image.